# How do I save plot images in R?

Tags: r, plot, save

I have created a plot from a very large vector (magnitude of 10^7). The problem with the usual way of saving the plot as a pdf file is that the pdf file comes out as a very large file of around 10MB. I don't want such a large size for a simple time series plot. How do I save the plot such that the size is small enough to be at most 100kilobytes?

Comment: the standard answer is that you probably don't need to plot all those points, but if you think you really do, then a raster format like `png` with good resolution will produce a much lighter output file.

Comment: `PDF`s will be large because they use vector graphics (which also makes them better for resizing, zooming, etc). Other formats have a fixed resolution which will make their size independent of number of points.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

baptiste is on the right track with their suggestion of png for a nice raster type plot. In contrast to Jdbaba's suggestion of copying the open device, I suggest that you make a call to the `png()`device directly. This will save a lot of time in that you won't have to load the plot in a separate device window first, which can take a long time to load if the data set is large.

#### Example

```
#plotting of 1e+06 points
x <- rnorm(1000000)
y <- rnorm(1000000)
png("myplot.png", width=4, height=4, units="in", res=300)
par(mar=c(4,4,1,1))
plot(x,y,col=rgb(0,0,0,0.03), pch=".", cex=2)
dev.off() #only 129kb in size
```

[image]

see `?png` for other settings of the png device.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to plot the png file use the following command:

```
dev.copy(png,"myfile.png",width=8,height=6,units="in",res=100)
dev.off()
```

you can change `res` value to higher value if you want to output high quality graphs.

If you want to save the file as pdf use the following command:

```
pdf("myfile.pdf",width=8,height=6)
dev.off()
```

Remember to change the width and height values as needed.