# mclapply with points when plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, points, mclapply

According to R documentation mclapply() is the parallelized version of lapply(), but in this easy example mclapply() does not work when trying to use with points(). Any solution?

```
plot(c(0,3),c(0,1000), type='n')
x<-runif(100,0,1000); y<-runif(100,0,1000)
lapply(x,function(a) {points(1,a,col='green')}) #ok
mclapply(x,function(a) {points(2,a,col='red')}) #ko: does not work
```

[image: points for x=2 are not plotted]

Comment: I don't think a single plotting device is going to be open to each core in a call to mclapply. Better to save the results (of whatever your underlying operation is) in a list and then plot.

Comment: Hi @Marcinthebox is correct in that parallelizing it is not going to speed up because you need to put it in the same device. Either you write it directly to png, or you can try 1) xyplot in lattice or 2) hexbin https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hexbin/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of first recording the results with `mclapply`, and then plotting

```
library(parallel)

plot(c(0,3),c(0,1000), type='n')
x<-runif(100,0,1000); y<-runif(100,0,1000)
lapply(x,function(a) {points(1,a,col='green')}) #ok
L <- mclapply(x,function(a) {data.frame(x = 2, y = a)})
lapply(L, function(X) {points(y~x, X, col='red')})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marc , but I'm trying to pararellize when plotting to plot faster. Is it possible?

Comment: No, I don't think this is going to help. If the issue is that you have a lot of points to plot, then you should not do this directly in the plotting device; rather, you should open an output plotting device like `png`, and send all your plot info there before closing with `dev.off()`. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17477296/1199289

Comment: Got it. So I probably have to split my plot in many parts and merge many plots. Thank you!